# How does java type inference work?

Tags: java, types, static-methods

Can someone please explain how the following syntax works?

```
public static <K, V> HashMap<K, V> getMap(){
    return new HashMap<K, V>();
}
```

As in, if this method was implemented in a non instantiable util class of my own this can be used as a static factory method to create map instances, right?

```
Map<Integer, String> myMap = MyUtil.getMap();
```

would  then return a new HashMap with Integer keys and String values for its entries, am I right?
If so, how are the types of the key and entry of map being realized by the  compiler and VM?

I would really appreciate if someone could explain how Java does this.

Comment: Did you look at the [Type Inference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)?

Comment: @Codebender: That's not true -- give it a shot.

Comment: @Codebender I did try putting <String,String> and <Integer,String> worked fine. So confused right now..

Comment: Guys, I see what it does, what i want to know is how it happens.

Comment: @javabot: That's what the documentation will tell you. (BTW, apologies for my earlier now-deleted comment, I actually thought that wouldn't compile. Working in too many languages lately...)

Comment: @Codebender: Yes, but that's not the use case. (I don't really see a point to the use case, but I think the point here is type inference, not an actually-useful utility function...)

Comment: @ T.J Crowder yep I tried referring the doc, yet still unclear how this actually happens.

Comment: @javabot: Then your best bet is to say what it is you don't understand about it, in the question, referring to the parts of the doc you don't understand. (So people know what to clarify for you.)

Comment: @AndyTurner: Well yes, but that's just an obvious typo.

Comment: @TJCrowder "not an actually-useful utility function" such methods exist in Guava, to allow elision of generic arguments prior to the diamond operator, as well as for the advantages of using static factory methods over constructors directly.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Well, as it is, it doesn't offer anything above `= new HashMap<>()`. But yeah, I was thinking if you changed `HashMap` to `Map` in the `getMap` declaration, it would give you a means of controlling the type of map centrally, but the type of map you want is usually usage-specific, so...

Comment: (@javabot: For the avoidance of doubt: If I had a deep understanding of tpe inference in Java, I'd be having a go at answering this. But I have only a passing knowledge of it, wouldn't be able to add anything to what the docs say.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask 'how Java does this'. Java is defined in a language specification which does not dictate how the specification is implemented. So it's really up to the implementation to pick a solution. So if you really want to know how a particular compiler or interpreter implements type inference I suspect that will need to be addressed by people familiar with that tool.

If your question is really 'what are the rules' then you'll find they are explained pretty well in the [specification itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html), and in the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html), and in the [standard Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) (in decreasing levels of formality).

It's a pretty complex area with lots of knarly cases to handle - in fact it involves three processes to understand properly (reduction, incorporation and resolution). But if you are looking for a simple summary I would state it as "when instantiating a class or method, replace each generic type with the most specific type possible". In your case replacing `K` with `Integer` and `V` with `String` is the the most specific inference that makes sense.

Comment: You are right. I guess I was worrying about the wrong thing.:(